# How to add more than 7 links in the shortcuts bar?

Tags: users

I just noticed that there is a limit of links to add to the Shortcut bar. Is there any way to change this, I need no limit at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the [`shortcut_max_slots()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!shortcut!shortcut.admin.inc/function/shortcut_max_slots/7) function that makes that decision; fortunately that function wraps around the return of a variable from the database (also called `shortcut_max_slots`), so you can simply set that variable and be done with it.

There's no way to make it unlimited without hacking the shortcut module directly, so you probably want to go for a high number:

```
variable_set('shortcut_max_slots', 100);
```

Comment: I think the idea behind limiting the shortcuts was to keep it simple. If a user has too many shortcuts, then there might be a case where s/he may require another to mechanism to search for the shortcut itself ;-)

Comment: Well, there's a [long](http://drupal.org/node/682000) [discussion](http://drupal.org/node/1304486) (two links) about it and most of the people agreed that it was a mistake to add that limitation. I avoid that in a custom installation profile in which install hook I change that variable immediately.

Comment: I also think that is a mistake to limit the shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

You also can change it in `settings.php` like this:

```
$conf['shortcut_max_slots'] = 10;
```

Taken from here https://www.drupal.org/node/682000